# NEW LAPS on Server 2016 / WIn 10 22H2 Environment

Tags: windows-server-2016, windows-10, password-reset

With the latest April update which adds LAPS to windows 10 22H2 and above I find that to be incredibly helpful. What isn't helpful is that my environment is running with Server 2016. I have installed Legacy LAPS and enabled LAPs on the Windows 10 22H2 machines. The problem I have is that it is constantly:

> Event ID 10012 Output
>
> Copy The Active Directory schema has not been updated with the
> necessary LAPS attributes

The documentation on this schema is shotty at best because based on this error I should simply run  `Update-LapsADSchema` but that is for Server 2019 and up. I have also tried the Legacy one as suggested by the Learn page `Update-AdmPwdADSchema` but I did that when I installed Legacy LAPS and it tells me the Schema is also updated already.

To make it worse when I open the GPEdit LAP is not where the legacy location should be but the New one is.

```
Old: Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > LAPS
New: Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > LAPS
```

So what am I missing to get this to work. I can set the LAPs Options in GPO and it can see it on the machine but it will not set the password. It just keeps giving me the issue about the schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the issue here is that the legacy software need to be installed on the Windows Server 2016 Domain Controllers. ON the Windows 10 machines nothing had to be installed. Also ensure that the computers in the GPO have the ability to change the passwords or it will throw an error. Ensure that the AdmPwd.adml and .admx is moved to your group policy policies so they can apply after the legacy LAPS install. Then configure the settings in your GPO and then gpupdate. You can check the LAPs log on the Windows 10 machine to ensure it is working.